# _e in wordpress + <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">Home</a>

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

In wordpress we use _e when we have to print things.
Example -

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 tuts">
    <p><?php _e( 'We are sorry, but there is nothing here! You might even call this a 404 Page Not Found error message, which is exactly what it is. The page you are looking for either does not exist, or the URL you followed or typed to get to it is incorrect in some way.', 'tuts'); ?></p>
</div>
```

where tuts is a text domain. The above setting is trying to print something on WordPress 404 page. But what if I wish to insert a link that can navigate to the Homepage.

I think this will work - ">Home

I tried it like this -

```
<?php _e( 'We are sorry, but there is nothing here! You might even call this a 404 Page Not Found error message, which is exactly what it is. The page you are looking for either does not exist, or the URL you followed or typed to get to it is incorrect in some way. Go back to <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">Home Page</a>.', 'tuts'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like below:

```
<?php /* translators: %s: home page URL */
printf( __( 'We are sorry, but there is nothing here! You might even call this a 404 Page Not Found error message, which is exactly what it is. The page you are looking for either does not exist, or the URL you followed or typed to get to it is incorrect in some way. Go back to <a href="%s">Home Page</a>.', 'tuts'), get_bloginfo('url') ); ?>
```

Note as we're using `printf()`, that's why we're not using [`_e()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e), but we're using [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2).

**Reference:** [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) - PHP

Comment: Is this a standard practice in wordpress Premium Theme Development?
I mean plugins such s WPML will be able to Recognize these codes?

Comment: 100%. Feel free to practice.

Comment: Thanks! What is the utility of "%s"?

Comment: Please consult the linked reference. It's the replacement of the only parameter that's passed to printf.

Answer (score -1):

There are my code.you can use.

```
<?php _e( 'We are sorry, but there is nothing here! You might even call this a 404 Page Not Found error message, which is exactly what it is. The page you are looking for either does not exist, or the URL you followed or typed to get to it is incorrect in some way. Go back to <a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">Home Page</a>.', 'tuts'); ?>
```